# Ubuntu 17.10 autologin despite this uncheck in settings

Tags: auto-login

I have a problem with autologin in my Ubuntu 17.10. In settings I have uncheck "automatical login" but still, when I turn on system then automatic log in. I looking for a solution in the internet but still nothing. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you've given a password to the user. If not, please do that. If this is not the problem, then I will recommend doing a clean install of the OS again.

This is my personal opinion that you should move from Ubuntu 17.10 to some older version like Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 only to delete it in 2 days. So many softwares are not available for this Ubuntu version. It is not a stable release. My display couldn't work properly in that OS. It was sometimes like this image: [Image](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjdi4LeifjYAhXCr48KHe_1AaYQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shutterstock.com%2Fvideo%2Fclip-5602298-stock-footage-test-pattern-tv-bad-signal-fps.html&psig=AOvVaw3CVEPlPbTG_2tNsFQXjRvM&ust=1517140175984314). So many flaws in that OS.

Comment: Yes, I have a password for my account. I just install this system few days ago. SO I dont think system reinstall will help. But I can try.

Comment: Ok. Try and reply.

Comment: Everything work property. Thanks guys for help :)